# How to Resolve the Android Camera setParameters failed

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

We are used Camera functionality in our Application. App will be published in Google App Store also. but we are facing new problem is setParameters failed in our application some devices only like moto g second generation. Please find the error console and SurfaceView coding in below.how to resolve this problem please guide me. Thanks

```
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821): Process: com.example.surfaceviewtest, PID: 13821
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1962)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at com.example.surfaceviewtest.Test.surfaceChanged(Test.java:58)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:594)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
07-09 11:54:08.460: E/AndroidRuntime(13821):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/shareLayout"


        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <com.example.surfaceviewtest.Test
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/weather"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                android:visibility="visible"
                >

               <!--   android:background="#4FFFFFFF" -->

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"

                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="453dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="matrix"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="This is SurfaceView Test"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Answerofgod.blogspot.kr"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Answerofgod.tistory.com"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="share"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="explore"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/onOffFlashlight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textOn="Turn Off"
        android:textOff="Turn On"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Turn On/Off Camera LED/ Flashlight Android" />
    </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback{

    SurfaceHolder holder;   
    Camera cam=null;        
int width;
int height;
private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public Test(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public void init(){

        holder=getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

    }



     @Override
      public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
       Camera.Parameters myParameters = cam.getParameters();

       int   wid = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
       int hei = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

       System.out.println("wid"+wid);
       System.out.println("hei"+hei);
       Camera.Size myBestSize = getBestPreviewSize(hei, wid, myParameters);

       if(myBestSize != null){
        myParameters.setPreviewSize(hei, wid);
        cam.setParameters(myParameters);
        cam.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        cam.startPreview();
       // isPreview = true;


       }
      }

     private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters){
         Camera.Size bestSize = null;
         List<Camera.Size> sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

         bestSize = sizeList.get(0);

         for(int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++){
          if((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) >
            (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)){
           bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
          }
         }

         return bestSize;
        }





    /*@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

        cam.setDisplayOrientation(90);      
        cam.startPreview();                 
    }*/
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        cam=Camera.open();              

        try{
            cam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);  
            cam.setPreviewCallback(this);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        cam.setPreviewCallback(null);
        cam.stopPreview();
        cam.release();                  
        cam=null;

    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
          width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    }*/


    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
         Camera.Size previewSize = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
        int wi = previewSize.width;
        //System.out.println("wi======"+wi);
        int he = previewSize.height;
        //params.setPreviewSize(wi, he);
        System.out.println("wi==========="+wi);
        System.out.println("he======"+he);
        int w = params.getPreviewSize().width;
    System.out.println("w=============="+ w);
        int h = params.getPreviewSize().height;
        System.out.println(" h =============="+ h );
        int format = params.getPreviewFormat();


        int  wid = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
        int hei = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();




        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, format,w, h, null);





        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Rect area = new Rect(0, 0,w, h);
        image.compressToJpeg(area, 100, out);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(out.toByteArray(), 0, out.size());






        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
         //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()gr
            //     mtrxFreeze, true);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        //Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0,w, he, matrix, true);

        //System.out.println("shareBitmap   getHeight"+rotatedBitmap.getHeight());
        //System.out.println("shareBitmap   getWidth"+rotatedBitmap.getWidth());


        MainActivity.shareBitmap=rotatedBitmap;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately RuntimeException for setParameters method is really generic and does not provide enough info of why it failed. Double check all parameters, one by one with the following command:

`parameters.flatten();`

Answer (score 0):

try to change the code from :

```
myParameters.setPreviewSize(hei, wid);
```

to :

```
myParameters.setPreviewSize(myBestSize.width, myBestSize.height);
```

in  `public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height)` method